# "No hay miedo de que se dé ese a quien van a prender"

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palabras, verbos, vocabulario, expresiones

This sentence comes from the the [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/dar?m=form) for the word "dar" (explanation 48), as such I do not have context, but as a rule of thumb, the example sentence should be clear without context, however I have difficulty understanding meaning of the sentence. My best guess is:

- "ese" is a person
- "a quien van a prender" = they are going to arrest
  this person
- "se dé ese" = I would give up on this person
- "No hay miedo de que ..." = don't be afraid that ..., i.e. I would not give up

So "No hay miedo de que se dé ese a quien van a prender" = there is no fear that I would give up on that person whom they are going to arrest? It is kind weird, I give up, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make much sense to me either!
I think that the example phrase in the dictionary has an error, and is lacking the negation word "**no**".
To me, it should rather read as:

> 48. prnl. Entregarse, ceder en la resistencia que se hacía. 
>     *No hay miedo de que **NO** se dé ese a quien van a prender.*

which i would interpret as:

> *There is no fear about whom is not giving himself up, since is going to be caught* [anyways]

Comment: This makes more sense now. "ese" is the subject of "se dé" which is put behind because it has a clause to modify it ("a quien van a prender") which makes the subject long. If you interpret "miedo" as doubt ("Recelo o aprensión que alguien tiene de que le suceda algo contrario a lo que desea"). Logically "se dé" = no miedo, and "no se da" = miedo, the original sentence can make sense. I have marked the answer as correct answer.